# python compare items in 2 list of different length - order is important

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

```
list_1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

so in the list above, only items in index 0 is the same while index 1 to 4 in both list are different. also, `list_2` has an extra item `'c'`. 
I want to count the number of times the index in both list are different, In this case I should get 3.

I tried doing this:

```
x = 0
for i in max(len(list_1),len(list_2)):
    if list_1[i]==list_2[i]:
        continue
    else:
        x+=1
```

I am getting an error.

Comment: Element at index 3 is also same I guess  ?

Comment: You should get *three*; items at index 1 and 2 differ, and you have 1 extra element. The lements at index 0 and 3 are equal.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. typo there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the lists, counting all the differences, then add the difference in length.

`zip()` will only iterate over the items that can be paired up, but there is little point in iterating over the remainder; you *know* those are all to be counted as different:

```
differences = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
differences += abs(len(list_1) - len(list_2))
```

The `sum()` sums up `True` and `False` values; this works because Python's `boolean` type is a subclass of `int` and `False` equals `0`, `True` equals `1`. Thus, for each differing pair of elements, the `True` values produced by the `!=` tests add up as `1`s.

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
>>> list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
>>> sum(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
2
>>> abs(len(list_1) - len(list_2))
1
>>> difference = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
>>> difference += abs(len(list_1) - len(list_2))
>>> difference
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,5,7,8,23,24,25,32]
list2 = [5,3,4,21,201,51,4,5,9,12,32,23]

list3 = []

for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i] not in list1:
        pass
    else :
        list3.append(list2[i])
print list3
print len(list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [ZdaR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3051961/zdar) commented, you should get 3 as the result and `zip_longest` can help here if you don't have `None`s in the lists.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
list_2=['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
x = sum(a != b for a,b in zip_longest(list_1,list_2))
```

Comment: Why iterate over all the extra elements in `list_2` if you can calculate up-front how many elements you'll find there. It won't make any difference if there is just 1 more element, but what if there are 1 million? You can simply take the difference in list lengths.

Comment: And `zip_longest()` takes an extra argument, `fillvalue`. Set that to `object()` and you'll not have to worry about `None` values in the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, that is correct. But if you don't want to check for lengths for whatever reason or get also the matching entries with artificial values it might be of value.

Answer (score 1):

Can i try this way using for loop:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> ls1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
>>> ls2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i in range(0, max(len(ls1),len(ls2)), 1):
...     if ls1[i:i+1] != ls2[i:i+1]:
...         count += 1
...
>>> print count
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this (didn't change the lists):

```
dif = 0 
for i in range(len(min(list_1, list_2))):
    if list_1[i]!=list_2[i]:
        dif+=1
    #print(list_1[i], " != ", list_2[i], " --> Dif = ", dif)

dif+=(len(max(list_1, list_2)) - len(min(list_1, list_2)))

print("Difference = ", dif)
```

(Output: `Difference = 3`)

Answer (score 0):

Not much better, but here's another option

```
if len(a) < len(b):
                b = b[0:len(a)]
            else:
                a = a[0:len(b)]

            correct = sum(a == b)
```